# Nuget + NuGetPowerTools + Enable-PackageRestore = authentication failure behind Proxy

Tags: nuget

Last night, at home, where I do not work with a proxy, updated a NuGet repository using NuGetPowerTools / Enable-PackageRestore.
Worked great.

Came into the office, where i am working with the same Repository under the following conditions:

- in a VMWare based VM,
- using Bridged Networking,
- Reinstalled NuGet today, restarted (to be sure I have latest version)
- runnning under an account in a DEV Domain (ie, DEV\Me)
- Accessing the outer world via a Proxy that requires a corp Domain Account (ie, CORP\Me)
- Ie 9's Configuration/Internet Options/Connection is setup as:

  - Use Proxy:
  - Address: yadayada1
  - Port: 80
  - Bypass proxy for local addresses
  - Automatically detect Settings
- Above settings are correct in as much that I can access the web via IE9, Chrome, etc.

  - *NOTE:* Can list and download Nuget packages...it's just the new Build process that can't.
- As per suggestion on the web I have looked at DevEnv.exe.config and have the following settings:
  -`<system.net><settings><ipv6 enabled="true" /></settings></system.net>`

  - I also tried with these settings as
  - `<system.net><defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"><proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True" /></defaultProxy></system.net>` 
    so that DevEnv.exe falls back for to same connection settings that IE 9 is using. Didn't do it.

What I get for all this is:

> ------ Build started: Project: XAct.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>     Please provide proxy credentials:
>     UserName: Password: 
>   C:_Workspaces\XAct\CS.FF.XAct.Lib2.nuget\NuGet.targets(43,9): error : Cannot read keys > when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected > from a file. Try Console.Read.
>   C:_Workspaces\XAct\CS.FF.XAct.Lib2.nuget\NuGet.targets(43,9): error MSB3073: The 
>   command ""C:_Workspaces\XAct\CS.FF.XAct.Lib2.nuget\nuget.exe" install 
>   "C:_Workspaces\XAct\CS.FF.XAct.Lib2\XAct.Core\XAct.Core\packages.config" -source "" -o 
>   "C:_Workspaces\XAct\CS.FF.XAct.Lib2\packages"" exited with code 1.

Found (but unfortunately lost again) a thread somewhere on the net where I saw NuGet developers thrashing it out -- referring to downloading the latest build from their TeamCity (which I could not access/join) -- but the thread did not clearly say Eureka! at the bottom.

Thanks.

Comment: Appears this is the same problem as: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1655

Comment: As per the prev link, putting a nuget.exe.config file (within the solution's .nuget folder), containing `<configuration>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
<proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
</configuration>` doesn't seem to help...

Comment: Putting the above in the devenv.exe.config and restarting doesn't help either...

Comment: Using Fiddler (acting as a Proxy + Decryption enabled) see: Error Code: 407 Proxy Authentication Required. Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.

Comment: Just tried starting Visual Studio with RunAs under CORP\Me -- still doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work any differently with NuGet 1.6's package restore instead of the power tools version?

Comment: Have you tried updating nuget.exe itself (nuget.exe update -self)? It's unlikely, but perhaps you were running an older version of the executable that did not have some of the proxy fixes that were introduced. If that doesn't help, could you post Fiddler traces on the codeplex issue?

Comment: I find it many times useful to copy the failed command from the build output and paste it into the command line. A lot of information is omitted in the buikd output.

Answer (score 1):

Reiterating what Sky and Pranav mentioned - this issue seems to be fixed in NuGet 1.7 - see http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1655:

> *pranavkm wrote Jan 31 at 8:17 PM*
>
> Fixed in changeset 6c156e0dc214